# Macaulay2 stuck analyzing `simple' ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, macaulay2

I'm attempting to use Macaulay2 to compute minimal prime decompositions of various ideals.  I'm getting used to the program and I've been successful in simpler cases.  But with the ideal I present below, Macaulay2 gets completely stuck, even after letting it run a long time, as well as trying the computation on a much more powerful machine.  I'm wondering if there is some theoretical reason Macaulay2 cannot handle it, or if there is some round-about way I can get the minimal primes.

Anyways, I let `R=QQ[z]` and `I=ideal(z^2-z+1)` and work in the polynomial ring `S=R/I[x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]`.  I define the ideal of `S`:

`J=ideal(x0*x3 - x1*x4, x0*x3 - x2*x5, x1*x4 - x2*x5, y0*y3 - y1*y4, 
y0*y3 - y2*y5, y1*y4 - y2*y5, ((x0+x1)*(x0+x2)*(x1+x2)-8*x0*x1*x2)*(x0*(x1^2-x2^2)+(z^2)*x1*(x2^2-x0^2)+(z^4)*x2*(x0^2-x1^2))*y0-(x1-x2)*(x2-x0)*(x0-x1)*(x0+(z^4)*x1+(z^2)*x2)*(x1*x2+(z^4)*x0*x2+(z^2)*x0*x1)*y1, (x0*(x1^2-x2^2)+(z^4)*x1*(x2^2-x0^2)+(z^2)*x2*(x0^2-x1^2))*(x0+(z^4)*x1+(z^2)*x2)*(x1*x2+(z^4)*x0*x2+(z^2)*x0*x1)*y1-(x0*(x1^2-x2^2)+(z^2)*x1*(x2^2-x0^2)+(z^4)*x2*(x0^2-x1^2))*(x0+(z^2)*x1+(z^4)*x2)*(x1*x2+(z^2)*x0*x2+(z^4)*x0*x1)*y2, (x1-x2)*(x2-x0)*(x0-x1)*(x0+(z^2)*x1+(z^4)*x2)*(x1*x2+(z^2)*x0*x2+(z^4)*x0*x1)*y2-((x0+x1)*(x0+x2)*(x1+x2)-8*x0*x1*x2)*(x0*(x1^2-x2^2)+(z^4)*x1*(x2^2-x0^2)+(z^2)*x2*(x0^2-x1^2))*y0);`

The goal is to find the minimal prime decomposition by computing `minimalPrimes J`.  But Macaulay2 just works indefinitely without success here.  As I said above, even on a more powerful machine in my department.  Relatively speaking, this is a pretty simple ideal, so I'm not sure what's going on.

The computation *does* work if you add another function to `J`, so is the problem that somehow this variety is underdetermined or something?  Geometrically, this is the total transform of a subvariety under a blow up.  And I need to use `minimalPrimes` to find the proper transform.

Comment: You can look into the code for minimalPrimes. These kinds of questions are better suited for forums for Macaulay2 such as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/macaulay2.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about that forum.  Definitely more appropriate.

Comment: People there are helpful and responsive. Good luck!